# Why can the exported class be assigned to a variable in ionic2?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

In settings.ts, I have the code below:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-settings',
  templateUrl: 'settings.html'
})
export class SettingsPage {

  }
}
```

and in the app.component.ts, we can write the code below:

```
settingsPage = SettingsPage;
```

Why can the Class name `SettingsPage` be assigned to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, Typescript is a superset of JavaScript. Since classes don't actually exist in a strict sense in JS, they are implemented as objects (with some extra's).

So what you're doing is simply getting an object `SettingsPage` (with a bunch of methods and properties) and assigning it to the variable `settingsPage`.

Comment: but when I assign the settingsPage with SettingsPage , use console.log(settingsPage) to print the output . and then I assign the settingsPage with new SettingsPage() ,console.log(settingsPage), the outputs of the two times is different.

Comment: when I should use settingsPage=SettingsPage,and when I should use settingsPage=new SettingsPage()?